# Specific elements from a web using jsoup

Tags: web-scraping, jsoup

I want to get the atomic clock from here http://watches.uhrzeit.org/atomic-clock.php and I wrote this program

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements; 
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class da {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
try{
    Document doc=Jsoup.connect("http://watches.uhrzeit.org/atomic-clock.php").get();
    Elements spans = doc.select("span[id=anzeige_std]");
    System.out.println(spans.text());

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

The problem is why it doesn't print anything(I am noob in this thing and I want to learn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to select an element by its id, use the format `element#id`.  The way you have it is for other attributes.

Second, the clock is on this html:

```
<div id="timer">
    <div id="timeText">
        <h2>current time CET</h2>
        <div id="anzeige_zeit">22:03:10</div> 
        <div id="anzeige_datum">Tuesday,  2. August 2016</div>
        <div id="anzeige_kw">calendar week 31</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which we can target with [CSS Selectors](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) like this:

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://watches.uhrzeit.org/atomic-clock.php").get();
    Element atomicTime = doc.select("div#anzeige_zeit").first();
    System.out.println(atomicTime.ownText());
```

**Output**

```
22:08:05
```

Comment: and for what # stands in div#anzeige_zeit?

Comment: @User124235 # is how we select on id attributes <div id=anziege_zei>.  For other attributes use div[attr=value], such as div[name=foobar] for <div name=foobar>